# PHP json not showing all related values

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Hello I have this php code for printing json

```
<?php

include('databaseconnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT product_id,product_name FROM products WHERE product_id='1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql2 = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ss.Name,':',sv.value_s ) as Specifications FROM specifications ss, specification_value sv WHERE sv.specification_ID = ss.specification_ID AND sv.product_id =  '1'";
$fetch = $conn->query($sql2);

$sql3 = "select GROUP_CONCAT(v.name,':',vv.value) as variants from variant v,variant_value vv where v.variant_id=vv.variant_id and product_id='1'";
$fetch1 = $conn->query($sql3);


$json['products'] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $json['products'] = $row;

  }

$json['products']['specification'] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch)){

    $specification_array  = explode(',', $row["Specifications"]);
    $speci_array = array();
    foreach($specification_array as $spec){
        $spec = explode(':',$spec);
        $speci_array[$spec[0]] = $spec[1];
    }
    $json['products']['specification'] = $speci_array;

    //array_push($json['products'],$row_temp);
   }

$json['products']['specification']['variants'] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch1)){

    $variants_array  = explode(',', $row["variants"]);
    $vari_array = array();
    foreach($variants_array as $var){
        $var = explode(':',$var);
        $vari_array[$var[0]] = $var[1];
    }
    $json['products']['specification']['variants'] = $vari_array;

    //array_push($json['products'],$row_temp);
   }


echo Json_encode($json);

?>
```

and output of this is

```
{
    "products": {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_name": "Face Wash",
        "specification": {
            "brand": "Python",
            "product_Description": "very good",
            "variants": {
                "size": "long"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in this i have one more value for variant i.e.
"size":"small" and that is not showing up.
sorry for bad English please ask me for any clarification before answering

my desired output

```
{
    "products": {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_name": "Face Wash",
        "specification": {
            "brand": "Python",
            "product_Description": "very good",
            "variants": {
                "size": "small"
                "size": "long"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do '$vari_array[$var[0]][] = $var[1];'  now the size is multidimensional array.

Comment: thanks it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do '$vari_array[$var[0]][] = $var[1];' now the size is multidimensional array. 
as shown by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993125/wisdmlabs in comments

Answer (score 2):

You can't add same key `size` twice. The previous key gets overwritten by later.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are repeating the key `size` again the values are being overwritten. Pass all the required values which are belonging to the same Key in an array.

Answer (score 0):

yes you cant use same key name ..
you can get like

```
{
    "products": {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_name": "Face Wash",
        "specification": {
            "brand": "Python",
            "product_Description": "very good",
            "variants": [{"size": "small"},{"size": "long"}]
        }
    }
}
```